# Issue Running an Initialization Script with Nginx Docker Container

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile, docker-entrypoint

I am creating a Nginx docker image that I'll be using as a reverse proxy component in ECS/Fargate in AWS.  I'm using the official Nginx image as the base image (1.17.5).

When the container starts I'm trying to run a bash script from an ENTRYPOINT to go out to the AWS Parameter Store and retrieve certificate info.  This work fine, however when I try to add a parameter to pass to the bash script (e.g. ENTRYPOINT ["installcerts.sh", "AppName"] it executes the script but the container terminates without error.

**I want the container to continue on to start up Nginx after the parameterized batch script.**

Here is my Docker File:

```
FROM nginx:1.17.5

# Install AWS CLI/BOTO3, JQ
RUN apt-get update &&  apt-get install -y &&  apt-get install awscli -y && apt-get install jq -y

# Copy Nginx config to etc/nginx
COPY proxy_ssl.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

VOLUME ["/etc/nginx/conf/d"]

# Copy entrypoint bash script to install certs from the AWS Parameter Store
COPY installcerts.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/installcerts.sh

#Pull certs from Parameter Store
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/installcerts.sh", "AppName"]

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And here is my "installcerts.sh" script showing utilizing the parameter passed in from ENTRYPOINT.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
-e
echo Installing certs...
aws ssm get-parameters --name /Certificate/$1/CRT | jq '.Parameters[0].Value' -r > /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.crt
aws ssm get-parameters --name /Certificate/$1/KEY | jq '.Parameters[0].Value' -r > /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.key
echo Exiting script.
exec "$@"
```

The "exec "$@" in the bash script is needed, but honestly, I don't completely understand how or why this works even after hours of trying to track it down.

The short story is:

If I use this, the container does what i want it to do but I can't send a parameter to the bash script.

**`ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/installcerts.sh"]`**

But If I use this, the script will run WITH the parameter successfully, but the container exits and Nginx doesn't start up.

**`ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/installcerts.sh", "AppName"]`**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set an `ENTRYPOINT` on your image, then docker passes that script the value of `CMD` (or whatever you pass on the command line after the image name).  For example, if you have:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/usr/bin/myprogram"]
```

Then docker runs, effectively:

```
/entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/myprogram
```

That is, Docker itself never runs `/usr/bin/myprogram`: it is entirely up to the `ENTRYPOINT` script to do that.  That is what the `exec "$@"` is for. This is a shell variable the evaluates to:

> Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one.
>   (bash(1) man page, in the "Special Parameters" section)

In our example, this would evaluate to:

```
exec /usr/bin/myprogram
```

...which replaces the current script with `/usr/bin/myprogram`.  But if we were to set `ENTRYPOINT` as you have in your question:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh", "appName"]
```

Then `exec "$@"` will in fact evaluate to:

```
exec appName /usr/bin/myprogram
```

And since `appName` isn't a valid command, the container will simply fail.

There are a few ways of dealing with this:

1. Do you really need to pass parameters to your `ENTRYPOINT` script? What about using environment variables instead?
2. If you *always* pass parameters to your script, you can use the `shift` shell command to drop those from the positional parameters before using `$@`. For example, for a script that expects two parameters:

   ```
   param1=$1
   param2=$2
   shift 2

   ...do stuff here...

   exec "$@"
   ```

   ...but this only works if you *always* pass two parameters.
3. You can implement command line option processing in your script using e.g. the `getopts` command:

   ```
   while getopts a:b: ch; do
     case $ch in
       (a) param1=$OPTARG
           ;;
       (b) param2=$OPTARG
           ;;
     esac
   done
   shift $(( $OPTIND - 1 ))

   ...do stuff here...

   exec "$@"
   ```

---

Having said that: I would opt for option 1 (use environment variables) as being the simplest solution:

```
docker run -e PARAM1="some value" ...
```

And then in your `ENTRYPOINT` script you can just use the `$PARAM1` variable where you need it.

Comment: That was the most easy to understand description about the use of Entrypoint+CMD+"$@" I have ever read (and believe me, I've read quite a few).  Thank you so much!  It's still obtuse, but thanks to you I get it now.  After I had asked the question I ended up use environment variables which totally works.  Still, you have demystified the way this works thanks (again) to you. :)